# Python csv file search

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to build a simple program that takes Roll number from a student and displays his results froma CSV file.
This is my CSV file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lpiwoybvbuwc95/results.csv?dl=0

And here is my python code:
        import csv

```
usn= input("Enter your USN number\nINSTRUCTION: Keep your caps lock on.\n")

f= open('results.csv')
csv_f= csv.reader(f)

for a in csv_f:
    if a[0] == usn:
        print("Name of the student: ",a[1])
        break

for row in csv_f:
    if usn in row:
    print(row[3]+" - "+row[4])

f.close()

input("\nPress ENTER to exit")
```

The problem that I am facing is, while displaying results, the first subject is skipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think the problem is that your csv reader starts at the index after the first result in the second for loop.
Try this to add the **f.seek(0)** to start reading the file from the start.

```
import csv
usn = input("Enter your USN number\nINSTRUCTION: Keep your caps lock on.\n")

f = open('results.csv')

for a in csv.reader(f):
  if a[0] == usn:
    print("Name of the student: " + a[1])
    break

# return to the beginning of the csv file
f.seek(0)

for row in csv.reader(f):
  if usn in row:
    print(row[3]+" - "+row[4])

f.close()
input("\nPress ENTER to exit")
```